# ubuntu 12.04, openvpn with network manager issue

Tags: 12.04, network-manager, openvpn

I need to connect to openVPN server from Ubuntu 12.04 installation.

So, I've installed network-manager-openvpn package and configure vpn connection.

Then I try to connect to vpn server, see success message but when I try to do something with network get the "Destination is unreachable" error, so I can't even ping the vpn server.

This is the client.conf file I got from server

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote server.com 1194
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert igor.crt
key igor.key
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

In network manager settings I set the gateway (server.com), Auth type - Certificate (TLS), set all certificates, enable Use LZO data compression option and Use TCP connection.
So, what may be wrong or where I can find some logs?

I had the same set up with Ubuntu 11.10 and it was worked fine, so it's definitely something missing in my configuration.

Thanks in advise.

UPD: When I run `openvpn --config client.con` vpn works fine

ifconfig when vpn is connected but not working

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:6d:04:e7:05:c6  
          inet addr:172.16.24.133  Bcast:172.16.24.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f66d:4ff:fee7:5c6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4097 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3700 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3843712 (3.8 MB)  TX bytes:596337 (596.3 KB)
          Interrupt:56 Base address:0xc000 
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.30  P-t-P:10.8.0.29  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:294 (294.0 B)  TX bytes:11813 (11.8 KB)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had probably the same problem. I found different 2 solutions searching the web.

1. Go to IPv4 setting->Routes and check the "Use this connection only..." . [This did not work for me]
2. The other is to specify a DNS: Go to IPv4, change the Method to "Automatic (VPN) addresses only" , and specify a DNS (for example Google's 8.8.8.8) [Worked for me]